# travis-ci postgres `SELECT EXISTS` query return different result

Tags: postgresql, travis-ci, pg-promise

I am working on some tests with `pg-promise` involve dropping a table and recreate a table.

All tests passes on my local machine. But on`travis-ci`, it seems to skipp all the `DROP TABLE ...` SQL, resulting tests fail.

Anyone has any idea why? Is it a permission issue?

Is there a way for me to further debug this, like connect to `travis-ci` postgres sever?

**Update:** I didnt put any code cuz all tests pass on my local env, so I thought it is just a `travis-ci` issue. The below are the bit that I think `traivs-ci` is skipping.

```
  afterEach('cleanup tables', (done) => {
    db.none('DROP TABLE $1~', 'syncTest')
    .then(done)
    .catch(() => done());
  });

  beforeEach('cleanup tables', (done) => {
    db.none('DROP TABLE $1~', 'syncTest')
    .then(done)
    .catch(() => done());
  });
```

**Update2:** After some further tests, it turns out that the test fail was because that

`db.one('SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name=$1)', [tableName])`

was not returning expected value. The query is returning `{ '?column?': false }` on travis, but returning `{ exists: false }` on my local env.

Is this a `travis-ci` issue? or postgres version issue?

Comment: One usually includes some code for this ;)

Comment: @vitaly-t I added some code that may be relevant.

Comment: @vitaly-t here is the repo if you have more time to investigate. https://github.com/xiaofan2406/pglize

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is because your test sequence is wrong, which is subject to a race condition, which you only see on Travis Ci because it is much busier than your local machine when running the tests.

To start with, try replacing your `DROP TABLE name` with `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS name`.

And then you may try using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name...`

Comment: thanks, you helped me find out what was causing the issue

Comment: @xiaofan2406 do you want to accept the answer or publish one of your own?